# authorize web-based API requests

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, xacml, xacml3

I have the following methods: OAuth, SAML, OpenID Connect, XACML, Shibboleth.

Do they work to authorize client to web API ? In practice, which one is the best?

Does they all support JSON?

Answer (score 3):

These are different standards with different purposes.

- OAuth is about delegation of authorization e.g. I grant Twitter the right to post on my Facebook account. Look into UMA (user-managed access) in addition to OAuth.
- OpenID Connect (OIDC) is an authentication layer on top of OAuth 2.0, an authorization framework. It brings together OAuth and OpenID.
- XACML is an access control / authorization standard based on attributes and policies. It is about defining access control policies that govern access to resources.
- Shibboleth is / was a federation protocol based on SAML.
- SAML is the de facto standard for identity federation across multiple enterprises.

OAuth, OpenID Connect, SAML, and Shibboleth focus on user identities, authentication, and federation.

XACML is exclusively about access control / authorization and can be used in conjunction with any of the other standards.

Whether any of these standards support JSON is a vague question. What for? SAML, AFAIK, is typically XML-encoded but the standard itself is not about its encoding. XACML usually uses XML for its policies but the access control flow can be expressed as JSON. In OpenID it is possible to use JWT, the JSON Web Token.

JSON Web Token (JWT) is a means of representing claims to be transferred between two parties. The claims in a JWT are encoded as a JSON object that is digitally signed using JSON Web Signature (JWS) and/or encrypted using JSON Web Encryption (JWE)

There are 2 websites you can look into to learn more:

- [Ping Identity provide lots of great information on SAML, OAuth, JWT, and more.](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/resources.html)
- [Axiomatics](http://developers.axiomatics.com) provide lots of great information on XACML.

Comment: Thank you David for your nice comment and really helpful.